# Is "The eviction process coincided with the deterioration of John's, Vlad's son, health." correct?

Tags: parentheticals, parenthetical-commas

1. The eviction process coincided with the deterioration of John's health, Vlad's son.

or

2. The eviction process coincided with the deterioration of John's, Vlad's son, health.

The second sentence seems cumbersome to me. *Vlad's son* is to be a parenthesis only, to remind the reader who is John, in case the reader forgot his introduction several paragraphs before. Are both sentences correct?

Comment: . . .  the deterioration of the health of John, Vlad's son.

Comment: (1) is definitely wrong (John's _health_ isn't Vlad's son). (2) needs an apostrophe 's' after 'son'. Probably better to re-word it as Nigel suggests.

Comment: @KateBunting The other possibility with #1 is that the speaker is addressing Vlad's son about the eviction process and health deterioration of some completely unconnected guy called John, which is just as problematic. ;)

Comment: @Kate Bunting Is then "The eviction process coincided with the deterioration of John's, Vlad's son's, health." correct?

Comment: @Nigel J I was told once by a tutor that I should rather avoid constructions " ... of ... of ...". But in the case of this sentence it sounds more natural to me than (1) or (2).

Comment: @JerzyBrzóska I would agree if it were three 'of's'. Two, I think is OK. What's a couple of genitives between friends ?

Comment: Yes, "John's, Vlad's son's, health" is grammatical. However , it might be better to say "Vlad's son John's health" or to completely re-word it as Nigel suggested.

Comment: Neither is right.  If I wanted to best preserve the wording you have, I'd write, "...deterioration of John's, Vlad's son's, health."  Or, since you actually say it's a parenthetical, I might use parentheses if I were you, writing, "...deterioration of John's (Vlad's son's) health."

Comment: @KateBunting I don't find "John's, Vlad's son's, health" to be grammatical to my ear. There are 3 's clitics but only two instances of grammatical possession.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possessive clitic ***’s*** can be applied to whole phrases (i.e. “the Queen of England ***’s*** hat”), including appositive phrases like in the example, even including phrases which themselves contain possessive clitics (“the sound coming from his wife’s brother’s new car’s engine”). In spoken English, the sentence would be as follows, and is perfectly grammatical, at least to my ears:

> The eviction process coincided with the deterioration of John, Vlad’s son’s, health.

Unfortunately, the combination with the appositive makes punctuating it awkward. Logically, the ***’s*** should come after the comma, but you can't put commas in the middle of words, so I would reorder slightly to avoid needing to use commas:

> The eviction process coincided with the deterioration of Vlad’s son John’s health.

Answer (score 1):

All technicalities aside, it's a rather awkward way to form the phrase and might be interpreted more easily if the structure were changed, for example:

The eviction process coincided with a deterioration in health for Vlad's son John.

Comment: *... a deterioration in health for Vlad's son John.* or *... the deterioration in health for Vlad's son John.*?

Comment: @Jerzy Brzoska In my experience the correct phrasing would be ; "we/I/they/he ...saw a deterioration in health"

Comment: Which kind of article to use probably depends on the larger context. I'd definitely use "a deterioration" if it was the first time the topic had been mentioned, but might use "the deterioration" if John's poor health had been introduced in previous sentences and I was referring back to it.